# Issue with s:property tag in struts2, Not showing spaces in text

Tags: html, struts2

We are using s:property tag to display string value on struts 2.

```
<s:property value="stringValue"/>
```

If "stringValue" has multiple spaces then it is showing only 1 space instead of exact text.

```
Ex: String stringValue ="Hello  World,  Welcome";
Output: Hello World, Welcome.
```

Here string text has two space in between but on application it is displaying only 1 space.

I have tried to use escapeHtml as false but same issue.

What is wrong with this tag?

Best Regards,
RKG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with the tag.

HTML treats multiple whitespaces as a single whitespace; that's just the way HTML is.

If you want to explicitly have multiple spaces you'll need to convert them to `&nbsp;` entities. There are a zillion ways to do that.

Comment: Thanks Newton, I didn't think in this way.